# Jquery plugin help defining default option as function

Tags: jquery

I need some help defining a a defoult option as a function and how I can call that function

```
var defaults = { option1: true, callfunction: .... };
```

Would `callfunction: function() {}` do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your `callfunction` is an empty function by default and will do nothing. Users of your plugin can pass a different function through the options to provide some behaviour.

Remember, that you can still pass some parameters to your `callfunction` if you need:

```
callfunction: function(param1, param2) {}
```

Comment: And how do I call that function inside the plugin: is this ok?
options.callfunction.call(this);

Comment: just `options.callfunction();` or `options.callfunction(param1, param2);` if you need to pass any parameters.